# powerpoint.Quit() function not quitting Microsoft powerpoint in python-pptx.Is there any work around to quit

Tags: com, powerpoint, python-pptx

Since i m unable to quit powerpoint it is giving me problems to convert into pdf.I am using pywin32 227 version and python 3.6.1 64bit.Is there any function in python to release COM objects.I am working on this for weeks but i m stuck here without any progress.Please help mw if you know anything

```
        def convert(files, formatType=32):
                    powerpoint = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
                    powerpoint.Visible = 1
                    print("ppt",powerpoint)
                    for filename in files:
                        newname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".pdf"
                        deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(filename)
                        deck.SaveAs(newname, formatType) 
                        deck.Close()
                    powerpoint.Quit()# NOT ABLE TO QUIT POWERPOINT
                    files = glob.glob(path) 
                    print(files)
                    convert(files)
                    print("after entering files")
                    os.remove(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the **TASK** this way:

```py
import os
os.system('taskkill /F /IM POWERPNT.EXE')
```